# Rails 6 pass variable to partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to render a partial for each conversation. I have the following code:

```
# app/views/messages/_new.html.erb
<%= simple_form_for [@conversation, @message] do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :body %>
  <%= f.text_field :messageable_id, value: current_user.id, type: "hidden" %>
  <%= f.text_field :messageable_type, value: "#{current_admin_user.class.name}", type: "hidden" %>
  <%= f.submit "Send Reply" %>
<% end %>
```

I want to change `value` of both hidden text fields depends on passed variable. Something like:

```
# app/views/admin/conversations/_show.html.erb
<%= render 'messages/new', value: current_admin_user.id %>
```

With below code I'm getting an error `Validation failed: Messageable must exist` which means `messageable_id = nil`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are not using the value you are passing to the partial.

Also, you need to pass both the variables

Try replacing the partial with the following

```
# app/views/admin/conversations/_show.html.erb
<%= render 'messages/new', messageable_id: current_admin_user.id, messageable_type: "#{current_admin_user.class.name}" %>
```

and use them

```
# app/views/messages/_new.html.erb
<%= simple_form_for [@conversation, @message] do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :body %>
  <%= f.text_field :messageable_id, value: messageable_id, type: "hidden" %>
  <%= f.text_field :messageable_type, value: messageable_type, type: "hidden" %>
  <%= f.submit "Send Reply" %>
<% end %>
```

**NOTE:** If you want the `_new` partial to render on its own as well

replace it with something like this:

```
<% messageable_id ||= current_admin_user.id %>
<% messageable_type ||= "#{current_admin_user.class.name}" %>
<%= f.text_field :messageable_id, value: messageable_id, type: "hidden" %>
...
```